# Binding a Button click event in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a button in my code behind file and want to bind the click function to an existing click function of a different button.  How do I handle this?  I was hoping for something simple like:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.onClick = otherClickEvent();
```

but apparently that's not doable.  Am I missing something here.  I'm aware of OnClientClick, but that only deals with the JS side of things apparently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
```

and later on the page

```
private void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    your code
}
```

Comment: Note this has to be set on every load, even during the postback itself. I had it behind my usual page load's `if postback, return`, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

b.OnClick += otherClickEvent;

To add event handlers in C#, use `+=`.  To remove them, use `-=`.

Answer (score 3):

AJ is almost correct here. You can use [Method Group Conversion](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2007/03/23/ImplicitMethodGroupConversionInC.aspx) syntax for this and write it like this:

```
b.OnClick += otherClickEvent;
```

Comment: Oops!  Right you are.  Editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET use

```
AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf FunctionName
```

instead